# rootFolderId not available in new SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

In my Code, I need this property to do something.
Have another way to get this information?

```
GTLServiceTicket *aboutGetTicket = [[GTLServiceDrive sharedServiceDrive] executeQuery:aboutGetQuery
                                                                            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveAbout *about, NSError *aboutError)
                                            {   
                                               if(about.rootFolderId!=nil)

                                                    {
                                                        NSArray *filesForPath = [GTLServiceDrive filesForPathComponents:pathComponents
                                                                                                 currentPathComponentID:about.rootFolderId
                                                                                                                  error:error];
                                                        if(*error==nil)
                                                        {
                                                            [files addObjectsFromArray:filesForPath];
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                executing = NO;
                                            }];
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? What have you tried?

Comment: We want to check whether directory and subdirectory are exist under the path. Could you give me some tips ? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GTLQueryDrive *fileListQuery = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesGetWithFileId:@"root"];
        if(fileListQuery==nil)
        {
            break;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        GTLServiceTicket *fileListTicket = [[GTLServiceDrive sharedServiceDrive] executeQuery:fileListQuery
                                                                            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                                                                GTLDriveFile *fileList,
                                                                                                NSError *fileListError)
```

from Google Drive API Says,
The root folder for every user is identified by the alias root. This alias can be used to identify the root folder anywhere a file or folder ID is expected.
https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/folders